# How to convert string to date format

Tags: javascript

I have string format data like below

```
Dec 26, 2014, 09:56 ET
Dec 31, 2014, 21:30 ET
Dec 30, 2014, 13:36 ET
```

And i want output in the below date format

```
26-12-2014 09:56:00
31-12-2014 21:30:00
30-12-2014 13:36:00
```

I have tried with the below code but it is giving different values. Correct me which syntax i can apply to convert string to date

```
str2date(input,"MMM dd, YYYY, HH:mm 'ET'")
```

Comment: What is `str2date(dateString:String, format:String):Date` ??? Please use a library with a minimal footprint e.g. [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com/).

Comment: `str2date` isn't a built-in JavaScript method, so we can't help you with its syntax... unless you tell us what that method is.

Comment: use regex to extract the different parts and then create a Date object out of it.

Comment: Yes, lets throw an entire library at a problem we don't fully understand. Classic.

Comment: P.S. Why is `'ET'` in quotes in your 2nd parameter to `str2date()`?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this if you don't want to use external libraries

```html
<html>
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function addZero(i) {
     if (i < 10) {
         i = "0" + i;
     }
     return i;
 }
 function myDate ()
 {
  var dateValue = new Date("Dec 26, 2014, 09:56");
  var d = dateValue.getDate();
  var m = dateValue.getMonth();
  var y = dateValue.getFullYear();
  var h = addZero(dateValue.getHours());
  var mi = addZero(dateValue.getMinutes());
  var s = addZero(dateValue.getSeconds());
  var newDate = (d + '-' + m + '-' + y + ' ' + h + ':' + mi + ':' +s);
  document.write(newDate);  
 }
 </script>
</head>
<body>
 <script>
 myDate();
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a library is your best bet. The following is an example using [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com/);

```js
var input = [
  'Dec 26, 2014, 09:56 ET',
  'Dec 31, 2014, 21:30 ET',
  'Dec 30, 2014, 13:36 ET'
];

var output = input.map(function(dateString) {
  return moment(dateString, "MMM DD, YYYY, HH:mm ZZ").format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss');
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(output, undefined, '  '));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.4/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Output:

```
[
  "26-12-2014 04:56:00",
  "31-12-2014 16:30:00",
  "30-12-2014 08:36:00"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can easily implement this using [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

```html
<html>
<head>
 <script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <script>
  var inputDate = 'Dec 26, 2014, 09:56:00';
  var formatString = 'DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm:ss';
     var outputDate = moment(inputDate).format(formatString);
     document.write(outputDate);
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script>
function strDate(str){
 var m = str.match(/(\w+) (\d{1,2}), (\d{4}), (\d{1,2}):(\d{1,2})/);

 var month = [];
 month['Jan'] = 1; 
 month['Feb'] = 2; 
 month['Mar'] = 3; 
 month['Apr'] = 4; 
 month['May'] = 5; 
 month['Jun'] = 6; 
 month['Jul'] = 7; 
 month['Aug'] = 8; 
 month['Sep'] = 9; 
 month['Oct'] = 10; 
 month['Nov'] = 11; 
 month['Dec'] = 12;

 return (m[2] + '-' + month[m[1]] + '-' + m[3] + ' ' +  m[4] + ':' + m[5] + ':00');
}

alert(strDate("Dec 26, 2014, 09:56 ET"));
</script>
```